# Dictionary with multiple string values for a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I need a dictionary that is composed by a lot of keys, and the values must be a list that contains lots of strings. (in Python)

I tried:

```
d1[key].append(value)
```

but Python says:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'.
```

I need something like : `{a:[b,c,d,e],b:[t,r,s,z]....}`

What could I do?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['key'].append(5)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key': [5]})
>>> dict(d)
{'key': [5]}
```

Comment: Yup, way better than my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
d1['something'] = []
d1['something'].append('a string')
d1['something'].append('another string')
d1['another'] = []
d1['another'].append('woohoo!')
```

Or, using `defauldict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = defaultdict(list)
d1['something'].append('a string')
d1['something'].append('another string')
d1['another'].append('woohoo!')
```

Or, using `setdefault`:

```
d1 = {}
d1.setdefault('something', []).append('a string')
d1.setdefault('something', []).append('another string')
d1.setdefault('another', []).append('woohoo!')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dictionary of lists, you can use `setdefault` method:

```
d1.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

But for me it looks like you have dictionary of strings, and `d1[key]` gives you string instead of list. It could happen if when you've tried to add first element of list, you used:

```
d1[key] = value1
```

and now value of dictionary for key `key` is string.
instead, try:

```
d1[key] = [value1]
```

and then you can call `append` method, because d1[key] is list

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the element of the `dict` as a `list` *before* you an append.

```
d1[key] = []
d1[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Alternatively: `d1.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` if you don't wish to use a `defaultdict`